Show law of excluded middle is valid
Example 1.12 from David Marker's An Invitation to Mathematical Logic (p. 10) shows $(\phi \vee \neg \phi)$ (that is, the law of excluded middle (LEM)) is valid in finitary model-theoretic FOL:
For any $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and any assignment $\sigma: V \rightarrow M$,
$$\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \neg \phi \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{M} \not\models_\sigma \phi $$
Thus $\mathcal{M} \models \phi$ or $\mathcal{M} \models \neg \phi$ and $\mathcal{M} \models(\phi \vee \neg \phi)$.

This uses Definitions 1.9 (a typical model-theoretic truth definition) and 1.11:
Definition 1.9 Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure. We inductively define $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ for all $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\phi$ and all assignments $\sigma$. Intuitively, $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ means " $\phi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$ under assignment $\sigma . "$

If $\phi$ is $t_1=t_2$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $t_1^{\mathcal{M}}[\sigma]=t_2^{\mathcal{M}}[\sigma]$.
If $\phi$ is $R\left(t_1, \ldots, t_{n_R}\right)$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $\left(t_1^{\mathcal{M}}[\sigma], \ldots, t_{n_R}^{\mathcal{M}}[\sigma]\right) \in$ $R^{\mathcal{M}}$.
If $\phi$ is $\neg \psi$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \not\models_\sigma \psi$.
If $\phi$ is $(\psi \wedge \theta)$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \psi$ and $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \theta$.
If $\phi$ is $(\psi \vee \theta)$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \psi$ or $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \theta$.
If $\phi$ is $\exists v_j \psi$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if there is $a \in M$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models_{\sigma\left[\frac{a}{v_j}\right]} \psi$.
If $\phi$ is $\forall v_j \psi$, then $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \models_{\sigma\left[\frac{a}{v_j}\right]} \psi$ for all $a \in M$.

If $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ we say that $\mathcal{M}$ with assignment $\sigma$ satisfies $\phi$ or $\phi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$ with assignment $\sigma$.
Definition 1.11 We say that an $\mathcal{L}$-formula is valid if $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ for every $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and every assignment $\sigma: V \rightarrow M$.

I want to confirm that I understand what is happening in the proof of LEM shown in Example 1.12.
First, the initial line is simply a restatement of Def 1.9.3, i.e. (using natural language to signify our metalogical connectives (except for $\iff$), similar to Definition 1.9):
$$\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \neg \phi \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{M} \not\models_\sigma \phi \equiv \text{not($\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$)} \tag{*}$$
holds for any structure and any assignment, by definition of $\models$ (seen in Def 1.9). In particular, note $\not\models$ is a symbol of our metalanguage, not the language $\mathcal{L}$.
Next, within our metalanguage we 'postulate' that the law of excluded middle holds as a metatautology - that is, for any well formed metaformula $P$:
$$(P \text{ or } \text{not($P$)})$$
is 'true'. Example 1.12 would be meaningless if $\phi$ were not a well-formed formula, thus we can construct the well-formed metaformula $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ in our metalanguage (similarly for $\neg\phi$ and $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \neg\phi$), for any $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and assignment $\sigma$. Therefore, by substituting $P \equiv (\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi)$:
$$[(\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi) \text{ or } \text{not($\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$)}] \equiv [(\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi) \text{ or } (\mathcal{M} \not\models_\sigma \phi)]$$
But by our (*) equation, this holds if and only if:
$$[(\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi) \text{ or } (\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \neg\phi)]$$
which by Def 1.9.5, holds if and only if:
$$[(\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma (\phi \vee \neg\phi)]$$
As already stated, the initial metatautology holds for any structure and assigment. The statement immediately above holds if and only the initial metatautology holds, thus $(\phi \vee \neg\phi)$ is valid.

I would appreciate any critique of my reasoning. I understand that I have made the proof tediously verbose, and introduced a barrage of undefined concepts (meta-whatevers). My intention was to draw out the fact that the 'proof' LEM is valid in Marker's finitary model-theoretic FOL simply amounts to applying the inductive definition of the satisfaction relation, alongside the assumption that LEM holds in the metalanguage. Perhaps I'm just straight up wrong, and I've missed something obvious? Or my reasoning is boggled in another way? Otherwise, I would also appreciate a simple "that's correct" so I can stop chasing my infinitely regressing tail.

It is correct, also if IMO it can be confusing to speak of meta-tautology etc. The meta- is not a formal language: it is simply math jargon: natural language+symbolic abbreviations (like $\vDash$).

@MauroALLEGRANZA i definitely think my discomfort with informal language is a sign of my immaturity as a mathematician. i find myself 'disappointed' that foundational questions in formal logic must be reduced informal systems like this. hopefully by having overdone it here, i might be more at ease to be less anal in the future.

two other examples in Marker, presumably solved similarly (i.e. invoking the metaprinciple along with Definition 1.9), are $\neg(P \vee \neg P)$ (never valid, by postulate of bivalence) and $\neg\neg P \approx P$ (valid, by principle of double negation).

Strictly speaking, we do not assert ex ante a law in this argument. We have the overall view of the object language $\mathcal{L}$ and the discourse it articulates; we express the view in the metalanguage, then, its corresponding $\mathcal{L}$-expression. Hence, this paragraph is problematic:

Next, within our metalanguage we 'postulate' that the law of
excluded middle holds as a metatautology - that is, for any well
formed metaformula $P$: $$(P \text{ or } \text{not($P$)})$$ is 'true'.

From the level of the metalanguage, we see that either a formula $\phi$ has a model $\mathcal{M}$ or does not have a model $\mathcal{M}$, that is,
$$\mbox{Either }\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi\mbox{ or }\mathcal{M}\nvDash\phi\tag{$\ast$}$$
We know that
$$\mathcal{M}\vDash\neg\phi\iff\mathcal{M}\nvDash\phi$$
Thus, we come to know that we can express $(\ast)$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ as an $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\psi\equiv\phi\vee\neg\phi$.
Therefore, we write
$$\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi\vee\neg\phi$$
because our main method in model theory is to make our inferences through existence of and relations between models.
It should be remarked that we frequently leave off such name-forming devices as quotation and use object-language and metalanguage in a hybrid style. Those interested in this subject may read about Tarski's conception of T-schema and carry on from there.

is $()$ not an asserted law (e.g., doesn't constructive metalanguage do away with $()$)?

In essence, the OP asks whether we have "postulated" the LEM beforehand in the metalanguage. At the meta-level, we observe all that go on in $\mathcal{L}$ and make inferences (e.g., see my answer). In the given argument, we only see that an $\mathcal{L}$-formula either has a model or not; that is, we do not see a quasi-model, etc.  Of course, you may stipulate the metalanguage in any way you think it's proper. But here, the author wants us to see the models (note $\mathcal{M}$ is not in the list of terms and formulas of $\mathcal{L}$).

i think i get it - instead of dogmatically asserting LEM in the metalanguage, we can  intuitively motivate our assertion that a subset of LEM holds (i.e. LEM when $P \equiv \mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ for any $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and any assignment $\sigma$) as 'wanting [the metalanguage] to see' all models.

Let us not say "dogmatically." We try to reason, first and foremost, via models here. Sure, we do not  "observe" as we do empirically in sciences. However, we take care of fine distinctions for the sake of rigour and precision.
